# Making Android Application by using Database

Tags: android, database

First of all, even I have basic knowledge about Java thanks to my college, I have not written a code before. I really do not know where I should start.

I want to make a quiz application and I know there are lots of sources for that app outside but while reading or watching a video about it, I feel like I am reading/watching Chinese books/movies.

Design is ready in my mind, I have also prepared over 1000 questions but I do not know the most important thing, "coding"! :( I want to write such a code that can do following bullets:

1. Home Page with "Start" and "High Score" button.
2. When users click on "Start" button, "Categories" page will appear.
3. After users select categories, first random question will be opened with correct answer button and 3 random wrong answer button. Of course, the position of buttons will be also determined randomly.
4. If users select the correct answer, new random question will be opened. If not, new page will appear that shows "Score" and includes "Home", "Restart" and "Categories" button.

I believe the app I want to make is not complicated. However, while watching a video, I realize that there are hundred lines of code that I am not able to understand.

I have also read text that says it is better to use a Database for more than 1000 questions. However, I do not also know how to connect database with app.

Here are my questions:

1. Do I have to buy a database or server etc?
2. As I said before, I have prepared over 1000 questions in excel sheet. Their columns' name are "Questions, Category, Answer, Image Location". Is there any easy way to connect it with a code that I want to write or connect it with a database?
3. I may copy and paste the code and may make it work but I do not want to do such a thing, I want to understand every lines of code and improve it whenever I want so that where should I start?

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Learn Java, SQLite, and then learn Android. Then you will be able to make that quiz application. And without learning these Languages, if you want to make your quiz application, then sleep and dream, it would be made. But don't ever wake up, otherwise too many crashes would be found.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Pravinsingh, have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start like that:
First make some tutorials about Fragments and Activities. 
From here you will understand how it is better to start:

1. Having one activity(max 2) and multiple fragments that each describe a transition.
2. Multiple activities with a fragment(at least in each of them).

Next lesson is about showing your data into a listview. Various tutorials exists about displaying data into a listview.

After that follows the understanding of how you get your data.

1. It can be from on online source, In this case you must read about json/xml parsing, transmitting over http/https(certificates, etc).
2. It can be from a database - sqlite. In this case you must read tutorials about how to create/query/insert/delete from a database in Android.

Once you understood of all that, you are ready to start connecting all the dots and decide what's best.
Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much Wana Ant. It really helped me a lot. I will follow your guide, have a nice day. :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. There a two scenarios here. In the first you'll use the android database, and store all things locally, there you won't need to buy anything. In the second scenario, you want everything to be stored remotely on the internet/cloud. Here you may have costs, depending on the database you want to use you need to buy a license, but there are tons of good, free and open-source data-bases out there just search for it. When we talk about servers, you'll have to rent one. Of courser there are free ones, but if you want to comercialize the product, I would not recommend those, but if you just wanna learn, go for it.
2. You can do this, but if are still learning the basics of program, I would not recommend it, stick with a data-base.
3. Start by studying the language(Java) and the environment(Android) and make your own app from the scratch. If you keep just modifying other's codes, you'll never learn to program.

Comment: Thank you very much Rafael. The information you shared with me is really precious for me.